# python flask how to pass a dynamic parameter to a decorator

Tags: python, flask, redis, python-decorators

I am using python flask framework. I write a decorator which will be need a parameter, and this parameter will be dynamic.

my decorator like below, will be get a key ,and using the key fetch data from redis.

```
def redis_hash_shop_style(key):
    def fn_wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            data = redis_hash(key)
            return data
        return decorated_function
return fn_wrapper
```

and I have a class to using this decorater, code like this

```
class ShopAreaAndStyleListAPI(Resource):
    @redis_hash_shop_style(key='shop_{}_style'.format(g.city.id))
    def get(self):
        # if not found from redis, query from mysql
        pass
```

As you see, my decorator need a parameter named `key`, and I pass the key like this

`@redis_hash_shop_style(key='shop_{}_style'.format(g.city.id))`

`g.city.id` will be get the city's id, if everything is ok, the key will be like this

`shop_100_style`

but I got the error:

```
class ShopAreaAndStyleListAPI(Resource):
File "xx.py", line 659, in ShopAreaAndStyleListAPI

@redis_hash_shop_style(key='shop_{}_style'.format(g.city.id))

File "/Users/xx/.virtualenvs/yy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
File "/Users/xx/.virtualenvs/yy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "/Users/xx/.virtualenvs/yy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 44, in _lookup_app_object
raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that 
needed to interface with the current application object in a way.  
To solve this set up an application context with app.app_context().  
See the documentation for more information.
```

I am quite confused , in flask, how to pass a dynamic parameter to a decorator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the docs for [flask application global](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-globals), `flask.g`, it says:

> To share data that is valid for one request only from one function to another, a global variable is not good enough because it would break in threaded environments. Flask provides you with a **special object** that ensures it is **only valid for the active request** and that will return different values for each request.

This is achieved by using a thread-local proxy (in [`flask/globals.py`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/globals.py#L61)):

```
g = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_app_object, 'g'))
```

The other thing we should keep in mind is that Python is executing the first pass of our decorator during the "compile" phase, outside of any request, or `flask` application. That means `key` argument get assigned a value of  `'shop_{}_style'.format(g.city.id)` when your application starts (when your class is being parsed/decorated), outside of `flask` request context.

But we can easily delay accessing to `flask.g` by using a lazy proxy, which fetches the value only when used, via callback function. Let's use the one already bundled with `flask`, the [`werkzeug.local.LocalProxy`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/local/#werkzeug.local.LocalProxy):

```
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

class ShopAreaAndStyleListAPI(Resource):
    @redis_hash_shop_style(key=LocalProxy(lambda: 'shop_{}_style'.format(g.city.id)))
    def get(self):
        # if not found from redis, query from mysql
        pass
```

In general (for non-`flask` or non-`werkzeug` apps), we can use a similar `LazyProxy` from the [`ProxyTypes`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ProxyTypes/0.9) package.

Unrelated to this, you'll also want to fix your `redis_hash_shop_style` decorator to not only fetch from `redis`, but to also update (or create) the value if stale (or non-existing), by calling the wrapped `f()` when appropriate.