# python flask API module how to pass a dynamic parameter to a decorator

Tags: python, flask, redis, python-decorators

I ask another question [python flask how to pass a dynamic parameter to a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994612/python-flask-how-to-pass-a-dynamic-parameter-to-a-decorator), I got the answer.

I am now using flask, and using [flask-restful api](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing) , which will be very easy to build restful api
and my code like this.

```
class ShopCategoryListAPI(Resource):
    #@redis_hash_shop(shop_id=LocalProxy(lambda: shop_id))
    @redis_hash_shop(shop_id)
    def get_shop(self, shop_id):
        return Shop.query.get(shop_id)

    def get(self, shop_id):
        shop = self.get_shop(shop_id)
        pass
```

I want to pass a `shop_id` to a decorator before I query shop from mysql, and here is my decorator demo.

```
def redis_hash_shop(shop_id):
    def fn_wrapper(fn):
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            key = 'shop:{}'.format(shop_id)
            if redis_store.exists(key):
                return redis_store.hgetall(key)
            else:
                shop = fn(*args, **kwargs)
                pass
        return decorated_function
    return fn_wrapper
```

it's just a demo, which will be get shop info in redis before query from mysql.

And I go the error. It tells us a  `Unresolved reference error`

Anyone who knows how to fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: `shop_id` needs to be defined outside of the function/decorator.

Comment: @wmorrell I am using flask-Restful, and cannot define shop_id outside of the function,here have a demo, http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing

Comment: Do you use PyCharm?

Comment: @lapinkoira yes ,PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is because `shop_id` is not a name in scope at the time it is used. A Python function decorator basically passes the defined function to the decorator function, and assigns the result back to the original name; so

```
@redis_hash_shop(shop_id)
def get_shop(self, shop_id):
    return Shop.query.get(shop_id)
```

is the same as:

```
def get_shop(self, shop_id):
    return Shop.query.get(shop_id)
fn_wrapper = redis_hash_shop(shop_id)
get_shop = fn_wrapper(get_shop)
```

The error `Unresolved reference 'shop_id'` is telling you exactly what is wrong: `shop_id` is not defined before it is used. Parameters to a function cannot be used as parameters to the function decorator, because there is no way for Python to know what a function will be called with when the function is *defined*, only when it is *called*.